# Entity DbSet and Any() producing true on empty collection

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a weird error I cannot understand. After setting breakpoints and local watches it came to this:

[image]

How can `_temp` be true (i.e., the collection `db.Users` contains a user of name "dummy") although the collection `db.Users` is empty?

For completeness:

```
public class DBCUsers : DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
}

public class User {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DbSet<T>.Local` contains a collection of entries already retrieved from the database by previous queries. Among other things, the idea is to save unnecessary round trips.

Unless you have previously executed queries in the context to retrieve `User` entities, `Local` will be empty. Your call to `Any()` can be translated into a SQL query which returns a boolean, so it does not cause the context to retrieve any entities.

To resolve your problem, either use the straightforward `db.Users.Count()`, which will query the database to get the count, or populate `Local` with a call to `Load()`, which as of EF6 is available in `QueryableExtensions` in `System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm rather new to database queries. But isn't the line above, i.e., the one that starts with `var _temp` a query such that `locals` should be populated (at least partially, with the "dummy" entry)?

Comment: No: "Your call to Any() can be translated into a SQL query which returns a boolean, so it does not cause the context to retrieve any entities". All EF needs to know is if the record exists, so the query will be something along the lines of a call to `EXISTS()` in SQL. Loading the whole entity isn't necessary.